# flipping a polygon with boost:geometry

Tags: c++, boost, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

What is the recommended way to flip a polygon horizontally so that its [bounding box](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/envelope/envelope.html) remains constant?

Comment: Is there more than one sensible method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use boost::geometry::for_each_point, supplying a functor which calculates the flipped coordinates (using e.g. an x-coordinate member variable calculated before using boost::geometry::envelope).

Or you can use boost::geometry::transform using a matrix transformer

Either way should work, there is no recommended way